# Sum of Array Elements is Zero

Tags: java, arrays, math

I'm trying to solve one problem but not able to find out any clue to solve this problem. Coding I can do but the only problem am facing is the logic.

I want to create an array on the basis of input number where final sum of array would be ZERO.

For example, My input can vary from `0<=input<=99`. Lets says if its 5 then my array should be like this.

```
[1,2,3,4,-10]
```

Note: All elements of an array should be distinct.

Can anyone share any idea....?

Comment: How did you come up with that example?

Comment: @ScottHunter, Does it matters ....?

Comment: Create 4 random numbers between 1 and say 12. Add them up, and your fifth number is that, just as negative.

Comment: "Does it matters ....?" - Yes it does matter. You as a human applied some logic to come up with that example so translating that logic to code would be a good start.

Comment: It's unclear to me. How the input is generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial answer is `[0, 1, ..., N-1, -N*(N-1)/2]`

Comment: If I give 10 as input number, It would be 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 =45 and -55....How it will work....?=

Comment: My bad, last item should have been -N*(N-1)/2, see my edited answer